# Trouble Interfacing Errors Between C and Lua: Seeking Solutions

Tags: c, debugging, error-handling, lua, ffi

Hello Stack Exchange Community,

I am facing a challenging issue with a project that involves interfacing between C and Lua code. The project utilizes Lua for scripting and C for certain critical computations. However, I'm encountering errors that seem to occur within the C code but are triggered via Lua.

The primary snippet causing the issue involves an xpcall function in Lua that wraps a C function call:

`xpcall(function() ffiC.gkyl_range_init(r, r._ndim, r._lower, r._upper) end, function() print("Error in gkyl_range_init") end)`

Despite using `xpcall` to catch errors, I am still experiencing C errors without the corresponding print statement. This raises questions about how I can accurately trace the Lua-C interface to pinpoint the exact source of the error.

**Specifically, my challenge is:
**

Obscured C Errors: Even with `xpcall`, the error messages originating from the C library aren't being properly captured or displayed, leaving me unsure about the exact cause. I can fix the errors, but I ultimately want to work out how the code can error in a graceful way rather than spitting out an error in the C code with no context of what called it in the Lua scripting.

**An Alternative Approach I've Considered:
**

- Using GDB for debugging: I've attempted to debug the code using GDB. However, the backtrace provided within GDB seems limited, indicating "No stack" and referencing missing debug symbols for specific components (openmpi040101-cuda111-gcc-runtime-4.1.1-126.sdl8.mellanox.x86_64). Our code is run on servers that, it seems, don't support the GDB interface. I've filed a ticket with the machine I work on. It seems nobody working on our code has attempted to use GDB to debug it.

**Seeking Solutions:
**

I'm reaching out to the community to gather insights and possible solutions to effectively debug and trace errors occurring between the Lua and C codebases. Any advice, debugging strategies, or thoughts on what might be causing the obscured C errors when triggered from Lua would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

What did you try:

I've been working on a project where Lua scripts interface with a C codebase using the foreign function interface library. However, I encountered issues where errors originating from the C layer were not adequately traced back to their corresponding Lua code, making debugging challenging.

To address this, I attempted to implement error-handling mechanisms within Lua using the xpcall function. Despite wrapping critical C function calls within xpcall to capture errors, the C errors persisted without triggering the specified error-handling function.

Additionally, I used GDB for debugging to trace these errors further. However, I faced difficulties as the debug symbols seemed to be missing, resulting in incomplete or unhelpful stack traces.

What were you expecting:

Ideally, I was expecting that by using xpcall, I could intercept C errors originating from Lua-invoked C functions and subsequently handle them gracefully within Lua. I anticipated that this error-handling approach would provide more informative error messages, allowing for easier identification of the source of the problem within the Lua codebase.

Moreover, when employing GDB, I anticipated having access to the complete stack trace and debug symbols, which would help pinpoint the exact location or function in the C code that triggers the error. This would have enabled a more detailed analysis and debugging of the issue at the C level.

Comment: Please edit your question to include enough C and Lua code that your problem is reproducible.

Comment: I mean, I expect ffi just makes a raw C call. Lua can only catch errors that are thrown using the Lua error mechanism which an arbitrary C library will know nothing about, and a general C interface like ffi will know nothing about any particular error mechanism of a specific library (and trying to catch internal errors like seg fault or infinite loop seems kind of out of scope...) If you want Lua to handle errors that are part of the library interface, then I would say check for them yourself as part of your interface code (whether in C or Lua) and translate them to Lua errors (or not).

Comment: OS signals should possible to handle in-process with POSIX `sigaction`. Haven't done this and doesn't seem like a fun way to debug. Illegal operand sounds like some kind of ABI issue maybe?? First FFI call failing? gkylzero C lib out of sync with Lua/FFI definition in gykl Lua? I mean, if things have gone horribly wrong, the error may be pretty unrelated to the actual cause of the issue. I image stack info could be difficult if JIT code is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Since your provided `function() print("Error in gkyl_range_init") end` as the error handler for your xpcall, you'll only print this line.

Instead you might want to try this:

```
local pOk, err = pcall(ffiC.gkyl_range_init, r, r._ndim, r._lower, r._upper)
if not pOk then
    print("Error in gkyl_range_init:", err)
end
```

This will work if `gkyl_range_init` fails with an error, if the function just returns an error code or message then you'll just want to print that instead, `pcall` will not trigger an error in this case.

```
local pOk, ret, err = pcall(ffiC.gkyl_range_init, r, r._ndim, r._lower, r._upper)
if not pOk then
    print("Error in gkyl_range_init:", ret)
elseif not ret then
    print("gkyl_range_init returned err:", err)
end
```

Something like the above might work if the function *does* return some information, if it doesn't then I guess you'll have to modify the library that you're using.

Comment: I tried this, and it still leads to an error in the C code. "Caught signal 4 (Illegal instruction: illegal operand)". It seems like the Lua function does not return any information, and the error is obscured within the library.

Comment: How did you acquire the error message?